# Why does my session get nulled when including a refresh token?

Tags: next.js, refresh-token, next-auth

I am using a Credentials provider (username and password). I can authenticate the user and have the tokens returned without issues.

I'm following the [Refresh Token Rotation](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation) article that Next-Auth provides.

However, the session never returns anything when I include the [refresh token in the initial sign in (line 72)](https://github.com/lawrencecchen/next-auth-refresh-tokens/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.js#L72). I can't console log anything in the session callback or even in any of the pages through `getServerSideProps`.

I can't even make it [passed](https://github.com/lawrencecchen/next-auth-refresh-tokens/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.js#L77) the initial sign up logic when including the refresh token.

If I don't include the refresh token, then the session data returns without problems.

What am I doing wrong? I've looked online and I keep seeing the same setup so I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably adding the refresh token your final token size is major than 4096 bytes.
See more at [jwt-callback docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback)

Comment: That was exactly it! Here's the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2213) that is currently discussing it for anyone who might have the same problem.

Comment: @Maria I Had the same problem... I resolve in this way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159271/problem-whit-nextauth-js-token-length-and-cognito)