# Problem whit NextAuth.js token length and Cognito

Tags: typescript, jwt, next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I'm trying to implement authentication in my Next.js app using NextAuth.js and Cognito.
Here's my problem: when the jwt callback is called I want to store in the session 3 tokens and other stuff but the token max length is 4096 bytes. How Can I implement this?
Thanks in advance!

```
  providers: [
    Providers.Cognito({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      domain: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
      idToken: true,
      scope: 'openid profile email aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        // Max 4096 bytes
        return {
          accessToken: account.accessToken,
          idToken: account.idToken, // Too long
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in! * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user, // Too long
          profile, // Too long
        };
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < (token.accessTokenExpires as number)) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      const sessionToken = session;
      sessionToken.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      sessionToken.idToken = token.idToken;
      sessionToken.profile = token.profile;
      return sessionToken;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

@SimoneUrbani, I was able to get the Cognito refresh token working using the NextAuth Google example. Here's my code for doing so in case it's helpful for anyone else:

```
async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://" + process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN + "/oauth2/token?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        client_id: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      });


    // Base 64 encode authentication string
    const headerString = process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const buff = Buffer.from(headerString, 'utf-8');
    const authHeader = buff.toString('base64');

    const refreshedTokensResponse = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + authHeader
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await refreshedTokensResponse.json();

    if (!refreshedTokensResponse.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens;
    }

    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);

    cookies.set('accessToken', refreshedTokens.access_token, {sameSite: true});
    cookies.set('idToken', refreshedTokens.id_token, {sameSite: true});

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_in * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    };

  } catch (error) {

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What a lifesaver. :) You should contribute this to the official docs!

Answer (score 2):

I solved by export a function which require two parameters: `req` (the request) and `res` (the response). These params allow me to set and get all the cookies I want.
This is my code:

```
const getOptions = (req, res) => ({
  providers: [
    Providers.Cognito({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      domain: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
      idToken: true,
      scope: 'openid profile email aws.cognito.signin.user.admin',
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
        cookies.set('userId', user.id);
        cookies.set('idToken', account.idToken);
        // Max 4096 bytes
        return {
          accessToken: account.accessToken,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in! * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
        };
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < (token.accessTokenExpires as number)) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
      const userId = cookies.get('userId');
      const idToken = cookies.get('idToken');

      const sessionToken = session;
      sessionToken.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      sessionToken.idToken = idToken;
      sessionToken.userId = userId;
      return sessionToken;
    },
  },
});

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, getOptions(req, res));
```

Comment: remember that cookies have a max too though. i went through all of this only to realize my object was too big for session and/or cookies

Answer (score 1):

A full example using the AWS v3 SDK and next-auth cognito config with TypeScript

You need to [augment your session type](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#main-module):

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    accessToken: string;
    accessTokenExpires: number;
    refreshToken: string;
    error?: string;
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession['user'];
  }
}
```

Then in your config:

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions, Session } from 'next-auth';
import CognitoProvider from 'next-auth/providers/cognito';
import { COGNITO_CLIENT_ID, COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, REGION } from 'web/lib/config/next';
import {
  AuthFlowType,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  InitiateAuthCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';

if (!REGION) throw new Error('REGION is not set');
if (!COGNITO_CLIENT_ID) throw new Error('COGNITO_CLIENT_ID is not set');
if (!COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID) throw new Error('COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID is not set');

const refreshCognitoAccessToken = async (token: JWT) => {
  const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: REGION });
  const command = new InitiateAuthCommand({
    AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH,
    ClientId: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
    AuthParameters: {
      REFRESH_TOKEN: token.refreshToken as string,
    },
  });
  const response = await client.send(command);
  return response.AuthenticationResult;
};

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      issuer: `https://cognito-idp.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`,

      // use cognito for token signing
      // https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/4707
      clientSecret: '',
      client: {
        token_endpoint_auth_method: 'none',
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    // need to handle token refresh https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation
    jwt: async ({ token, account, user }) => {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          // save token to session for authenticating to AWS
          // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at ? account.expires_at * 1000 : 0,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        };
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < (token as Session).accessTokenExpires) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      const refreshedTokens = await refreshCognitoAccessToken(token);
      return {
        ...token,
        accessToken: refreshedTokens?.AccessToken,
        accessTokenExpires: refreshedTokens?.ExpiresIn ? Date.now() + refreshedTokens?.ExpiresIn * 1000 : 0,
        refreshToken: refreshedTokens?.RefreshToken ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
      };
    },

    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (!session?.user || !token?.accessToken) {
        console.error('No accessToken found on token or session');
        return session;
      }
      session.user = token.user as Session['user'];
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string;
      session.error = token.error as string | undefined;

      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: This is giving me the following error: ` OPError: invalid_client` . Will follow up if I figure it out.

Comment: Looks like next-auth may have fixed the issue with the CognitoProvider, it seems to be working now that I've changed `clientSecret: "", client: { token ....` to just `clientSecret: "SECRET_GOES_HERE"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be helpful at all but maybe so. I am experiencing this same issue on an app I'm building. I found an issue discussion regarding this on the NextAuth Github site and maybe that will be helpful to you: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2213 I couldn't really figure out how that was going to help me as I still needed the idToken to add to the header for requests that require authorization. I'm new to Next so maybe I'm just dense, so I explored using the database option as well only with no JWT but then the idToken doesn't get saved in the database so you don't have that available for the authentication header calls.

Finally, what I think might work (at least for me) is using both the database and JWT where I'm adding the idToken into my session data so I can start querying right away but have the acccessToken and refreshToken in the database.

I added a db.js file in /lib (after installing [serverless-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql))

```js
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql';

const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS
  }
});
export default async function executeQuery({query, values}) {
  try {
    const results = await db.query(query, values);
    await db.end();
    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    return {error};
  }
}
```

Then, I created a file in /pages/api called get-tokens.js:

```js
import {getSession} from "next-auth/client";
import executeQuery from "../../lib/db";


const getTokenData = async (session) => {
  try {
    const result = await executeQuery({
      query: 'SELECT users.id, users.email, accounts.refresh_token, accounts.access_token FROM users LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.user_id = users.id WHERE users.email = ?',
      values: session.userData.email,
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await getSession({req});
    let tokenData = await getTokenData(session);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(tokenData));

  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
    res.status(405).end;
  }

}
```

This will return a JSON object that has the email, refresh_token and access_token. You can easily adjust that to only return what you want via the SQL query or add other elements as needed/wanted.

Here are my jwt and session callbacks in the [...nextauth].js file:

```js
async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {

  if (account?.idToken) {
    token.idToken = account.idToken;
  }

  return token
},
async session(session, token) {

  if (token?.idToken) {
    session.idToken = token.idToken;
  }

  return session;
},
```

Comment: @SimoneUrbani No problem. Thank you for posting your solution below. I didn't realize that you could set cookies within the API NextAuth file. Your solution is much more elegant! Would you mind posting your solution to refresh the access token? I have a working solution but it's a bit of a Frankenstein's monster. I scoured the internet looking for a comprehensive solution to using Cognito and the idToken with NextAuth and couldn't find anything. You might consider creating a Medium post about how you solved it.

Comment: I just copy/past from google and I don't test it yet. When I'm sure that my solution works, I will post it!